# login screen to show before shell in prism 6

Tags: shell, authentication, prism-6

Im working on wpf sample app with Prim 6...I have login window and Main Screen(**Shell**)...Im using unity as BootStrapper.

I want to show login screen before shell loading...Im doing this way...

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<**Login**>();
        }
```

In above case, Login screen appears...on authentication, it goes to shell screen but RegionNavigation is not working....

If i keep

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<**Shell**>();
        }
```

Everything works but login screen is not displayed first. Hence, cant authenticate...

Can anyone suggest to how to solve this ?

Regards,
Pawan